# Инструкция из while выполняется до проверки условия.

Tags: c++

К примеру есть цикл do while(назовем его вторым) и в нем инструкции :

```
cin >> c;
cout << "Неправильный символ! Повторите ввод.\n";
```

И есть перед ним цикл do while(первый) и его инструкции :

```
cout << "Введите название файла\n"; 
getline(cin, filename);
```

Так вот, после завершения первого цикла, во втором начинает выполняться сначала инструкция `cout << "Неправильный символ! Повторите ввод.\n";`, а не инструкция `cin >> c;`, а потом уже после проверки условия, выполняется как положено.

Ещё есть третий цикл, просто while, с условием `while(getline(cin, str))` и внутри `cout << "Неправильные данные! Повторите ввод.\n";`. И в нем тоже как будто игнорируется условие и сразу исполняется инструкция, а на следующий раз уже нормально.
Есть ли этому какое-то объяснение?

**UPD**
Вот пример кода :
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        cin >> c;
    }
    while(c != '+');

    string str_input;
    while(getline(cin, str_input))
    {   
            cout << "2";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

После того как ввести +, сразу выводится 2, хотя должно же условие сначала выполниться.

Comment: Может, просто приведите код? И ещё, вы бы прошлись под отладчиком, обычно половина вопросов при этом снимается.

Comment: Печально, но отладчиком пользоваться не умею, то есть ещё не брался за его освоение. Посоветуете какой-нибудь материал для изучения по этому поводу?

Comment: @strol: Практика, практика и ещё раз практика. Там всё интуитивно ясно, поверьте мне.

(К gdb, конечно, надо привыкать, но и для него наверняка есть куча графических оболочек.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот это спрашивалось много раз уже.

```
cin >> c;
```

оставляет \n в потоке

надо выполнить вот такое перед  while(getline(cin, str_input))

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'));
```

Comment: а если у меня есть макрос max, то как избежать конфликта имен?

Comment: @strol какой там может быть конфликт имён? Просто синтаксическая ошибка безо всяких конфликтов. Макросы рулят!

Comment: @alexlz: Макросы рулят [сильнее, чем мы привыкли думать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/197266/).

Comment: @VladD и эти люди запрещают мне ковырять в носу!